# VisualStudio cloud-based load test socket exception 100% of requests - webtest alone works OK

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, ssl, load-testing, msloadtest

I am taking my first steps with visual studio enterprise load tests.
I have created a webtest following this tutorial: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/performance-testing/run-performance-tests-app-before-release

The webtest works OK, hits my page properly and succeeds.
However when I have created a load test with this webtest, each request fails (regardless of the number of users, even with 2 users)

The error is

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond 10.27.8.6:443

and the stack trace

> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
>   Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception&
>   exception)

**The thing that potentially might be an issue** is the fact that I have a self signed SSL certificate that obviously shows the certificate error warning. However, this is something I cannot change for now, so the tests will have to ignore this.

Also, I used https://www.webperformance.com/download/ tool to do these tests and it all worked OK with a relatively high intensity, so this cannot be a matter of poor performance of the site.

Any idea what could it be?

Not sure what more details can I give than below (as I said, for sure its not a matter of performance, because similar load test with different tool runs OK. It is also not a matter of webtest being wrong because it still passes when run as single test).

Webtest setup

[image]

Settings:

[image]

Loadtest setup

[image]

Loadtest settings

[image]

Comment: Have you run the web test again after the load test failed? Does it still work? How are you sending the certificate in the web test and also when load testing? See also https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/45f83a21-35ca-4b79-9d20-a2db1af5c5b2/create-a-web-plugin-for-passing-client-certificates?forum=vstest#66b661bf-1654-4c71-9dd7-0f8bb51a2d63

Comment: @AdrianHHH Hey - yes, it consitently works when run as webtest. I am not sending the certificate, I am doing simple get/post requests to a site that runs with SSL

Comment: I think you need to explain much more in the question. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @AdrianHHH - all the info that comes to my mind is now there, if you have something specific in mind, please tell me.

Comment: Does the web site allow one user to be logged in at more than one terminal? All your simulated users use the same username and password. If a username logs in on one terminal then the same username logs in elsewhere are they automatically logged out on the first terminal? I cannot ask you all the variations, generally: what happens?

Comment: @AdrianHHH - yes, the fact that its the same user details does not matter, I run identical login/logout test with 50 users (single set of credentials) concurrently and its fine.

Comment: Did you find a solution I am running into the exact same problem.