# Turn off 'cloud-based' based mode for visual studio load test

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure-devops, load-testing

This is sort of a part two of the question here
[VisualStudio cloud-based load test socket exception 100% of requests - webtest alone works OK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45351491/visualstudio-cloud-based-load-test-socket-exception-100-of-requests-webtest-a)

In short, my loadtest fails all requests with a weird socketexception, but only when it is run as a 'cloud based' test.

So, my load test somehow (dunno how) is no longer a 'team services cloud based' unit test, but a *regular* one - and I see that it runs fine.

[image]

However, when I add a new cloud-based test and then click on the 'location' setting in my old test and pick anything (or not pick, doesn't matter), VS connects to my TeamServices account, the test becomes cloud-based and it is launched in a different looking tab, with 100% request fails.

[image]

**So, the question is - how do I turn off/toggle the 'cloud-based' mode for an existing loadtest?**

Comment: Not clear about turn off/toggle the cloud-based mode, could you provide the detail information? Regarding cloud load test, is the website can be accessible from internet? If not, you can refer to this article to do load test for an application that is not publicly accessible. [Use cloud load agents on your infrastructure](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/08/22/use-cloud-load-agents-on-your-infrastructure/)

Comment: @starain-MSFT - I think it's answered by Eddie below - thanks though:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the testsettings file in your solution/project, you should be able to change the Test run location from VSTS to local computer:
[image]

Comment: I agree with Eddie's answer, but expect to get one load test error about *"Geo locations configured with load test will only be honored with load test runs using Visual Studio Team Services and will be ignored while running your load test on-premises."* I have not found a way of suppressing this error.